# How did we apply Fubini's theorem in this proof?

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, laplace-transform, convolution, fubini-tonelli-theorems

I have troubles understanding the proof of the following theorem from my notes about Laplace transform $\mathcal{L}$.

> Theorem: Let $f, g : [0, \infty) \to \mathbb{C}$ be functions of exponential increase; $|f(t)| \leq M e^{kt}, \; |g(t)| \leq Me^{kt}$. Then, if $\text{Re}(z) > k$, the following equality holds:
> $$ \mathcal{L} (f \ast g) = \mathcal{L}(f)\mathcal{L}(g) $$

> Proof: We use Fubini's theorem to obtain:
> $$ \mathcal{L}(f \ast g)(z) = \int_0^{\infty} e^{-zt} (f \ast g)(t) dt = \int_0^{\infty} e^{-zt} \left( \int_0^t f(t-s)g(s)ds \right) dt = \int_0^{\infty} \left( \int_s^{\infty} f(t-s)g(s)e^{-z(t-s)} e^{-zs} dt \right) ds = \int_0^{\infty} g(s) e^{-zs} \left( \int_s^{\infty} f(t-s) e^{-z(t-s)} dt  \right) ds = \mathcal{L}(f)(z) \cdot \mathcal{L}(g)(z) $$

If I recall correctly, professor claimed that we use Fubini's theorem in the third equality, to interchange the integrals. However, I do not understand, how exactly did we apply it and what happened. How do we get the new borders?

Comment: Basically both integrals are equal to a double integral over the area $\{(t,s)\in\mathbb R^2\mid 0\le s\le t\lt\infty\}$ so you can either convert it to integral where $0\le t\lt\infty$ and then $0\le s\le t$, or, alternatively, first let $0\le s\lt\infty$ and then let $s\le t\lt\infty$.

Comment: To apply Fubinis theorem, you need the bounds to be constant. To do this you use indicator functions. For example $$\int_s^\infty h(x)\,dx = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}h(x)I(x \geq s)\,dx.$$

Comment: @StinkingBishop I really like this approach. But it does not use Fubini's theorem, right?

Comment: @Mason Wow, what an amazing trick! I wouldn't have thought of this, but it looks so trivial now ;)

Comment: @Matthew Bishop's method is the same as mine. He's thinking of all the indicators multiplied together, which gives you the indicator of that set.

Comment: @Mason How I see it, he just covered all of the area in two different ways; I don't think you need Fubini to do that? Or am I wrong? I've done wjat he does here multiple times and I never thoight about indicator functions, so even if they are used, they are used implicitly.